# Which version of C++ library on Linux conform to the "ISO C++ 11" standard?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards

Presently I've Debian Squeeze(AMD64 linux), libstdc++5 and libstdc++6 on my computer.

Do these C++ libraries conform to the ISO standard C++11?

Comment: What is the actual version of `libstdc++` installed, and what GCC compiler version are you running? If you're using stable/testing packages for Debian/Squeeze, you probably have GCC 4.4 and its associated `libstdc++`, and you can see what features of C++11 you get by cross-referencing the table on this page: http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

Comment: C++ lib version 4.4.5, gcc version 4.4.5,  g++ version 4.4.5

Comment: @birryree: that should be an answer. Well, I suppose the answer is "no, it doesn't conform, it's not finished", plus what you just said.

Comment: I don't think there's *any* C++ compiler that is fully C++-11 compliant yet.

Comment: @birryree your link is for "core" language features, not the library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No they don't conform fully, but they have elements :

[C++11 support on stdlibc++](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html) (this is for the latest version, not the one you have)

[C++11 support on GCC versions](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html)

Your best bet is to try [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/) (developed for clang but works with GCC 4.4 as well). You could try downloading and compiling the latest clang or GCC release as well.

Only MS has a fully implemented C++11 library in VC 11 (or so they claim, and yes, that doesn't help you, sorry).

Comment: I'll wait for the support in g++.

Comment: Note: from what I see on the clang mailing-list, getting libc++ to compile outside the Apple world is not so easy. Those who try should not hesitate to reach to the mailing-list and ask for help.